# Iterating on Tensorfow Dataset returns always a differently sorted array

Tags: python, tensorflow, tf.data.dataset

Suppose you have a tensorflow dataset that has values and labels. In my case I created it from a time series as:

```
f = pd.read_csv('MY.csv', index_col=0, parse_dates=True)
#extract the column we are interested in
single_col = df[['Close']]

#Convert to TFDataset
WINDOW_SIZE = 10
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((single_col_df.values))
d = dataset.window(WINDOW_SIZE, shift=1, drop_remainder=True)
d2 = d.flat_map(lambda window: window.batch(WINDOW_SIZE+1))
#create data and ground truth
d3 = d2.map(lambda window: (window[:-1], window[-1:]))

#get the total data and shuffle
len_ds = 0
for item in d2:
  len_ds +=1
d_shuffled = d3.shuffle(buffer_size=len_ds)

# split train/test
train_size = int(0.7 * len_ds)
val_size = int(0.15 * len_ds)    
test_size = int(0.15 * len_ds)
train_dataset = d_shuffled.take(train_size)
test_dataset = d_shuffled.skip(train_size)
val_dataset = test_dataset.skip(test_size)
test_dataset = test_dataset.take(test_size)
train_dataset = train_dataset.batch(32).prefetch(2)
val_dataset = val_dataset.batch(32)
```

Now for evaluation purposes I want to get the ground truth values of the test, so I am running

```
y = np.concatenate([y for x, y in test_dataset], axis=0)
```

but this is returning each time an array differently sorted, so it cannot be compared with the models predicted by the model. For example when running the above line in jupyter notebook and printing the first 5 values of `y` as `y[:5], one time I get

```
array([[26.04000092],
       [16.39999962],
       [18.98999977],
       [42.31000137],
       [19.82999992]])
```

another I get

```
array([[15.86999989],
       [43.27999878],
       [19.32999992],
       [48.38000107],
       [17.12000084]])
```

but the length of `y` remains the same so I am assuming that the elements are just shuffled around. Anyway with this I cannot compared these values with the predicted ones, since their order is different :

```
y_hat = model.predict(test_dataset)
```

Furthermore, I get also different evaluation results. For example,

```
x = []
y = []
for _x,_y in test_dataset:
    x.append(_x)
    y.append(_y)
x = np.array(x)
y = np.array(y)
model.evaluate(x=x, y=y)
```

each time the loop defining the arrays `x` and `y` is re-executed, I get different `x` and `y` arrays that result in a different evaluation result.

Comment: What do you mena by "each time" in `but this is returning each time an array differently sorted,`. At each epoch, or when you run the program twice, something else?

Comment: I modified my question trying to explain it. If still unclear please let me know

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Your problem :

by calling `shuffle` on the **whole** dataset before splitting it, you actually reshuffle the dataset after each exhaustion of the dataset. Here is what is happening:

- The first call of `y = np.concatenate([y for x, y in test_dataset], axis=0)` will exhaust the test dataset
- The second call of `y = np.concatenate([y for x, y in test_dataset], axis=0)` will see that test_dataset is exhausted, and will trigger:

  1. A reshuffle of the **whole** dataset
  2. The call to skip to get a dataset of the right size

You end up with potentially samples of your train dataset of the first exhaustion in the test dataset of the second round.

### The solution

If we look at the documentation of [`tf.data.Dataset.suffle`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset#shuffle) :

> reshuffle_each_iteration (Optional.) A boolean, which if true indicates that the dataset should be pseudorandomly reshuffled each time it is iterated over. (Defaults to **True**.)

**Set it to false** to have a deterministic shuffle. If you still want to shuffle your training set each epoch, you need to call shuffle on the train set.

### A dummy example :

```py
import tensorflow as tf
tf.random.set_seed(0) # reproducibility
a = tf.range(10)
ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(a)
ds_shuffled = ds.shuffle(10,reshuffle_each_iteration=False)
ds_train = ds_shuffled.take(7)
ds_train = ds_train.shuffle(7)
ds_test = ds_shuffled.skip(7)
```

Running it :

```py
>>> [x.numpy() for x in ds_test]
[5, 8, 4]
>>> [x.numpy() for x in ds_test]
[5, 8, 4]
>>> [x.numpy() for x in ds_train]
[1, 3, 7, 2, 6, 9, 0]
>>> [x.numpy() for x in ds_train]
[3, 9, 6, 7, 2, 1, 0]
```

*Try running it with `reshuffle_each_iteration=True` to see what happened in your own code*

Comment: Ok that is a step forward but even if the test set is reshuffled, being the elements in the test the same but just in different order, the evaluate method should always return the same value, shouldn't it?

Comment: I guess my answer was not clear enough. See if it is better now @FrancescoBoi

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Lescurel's answer, another working solution seems to be this piece of code from Kaggle that uses `sklearn`:

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
# Extract target values from the vanilla training dataset.
# Indices are generated along with the target values, which are used to filter dataset.
y_targets = np.array([ target.numpy() for _, target in iter(d_shuffled) ])
X_indices = np.arange(len(y_targets))

y_targets = y_targets.reshape((-1,))
y_targets.shape

#stratify array-like, default=None If not None, data is split in a stratified fashion, using this as the class labels.
X_train_indices, X_val_indices, y_train_targets, y_val_targets = train_test_split(
    X_indices, y_targets, test_size=0.15, stratify=None, random_state=53)

X_test_indices, X_val_indices, y_test_targets, y_val_targets = train_test_split(
    X_val_indices, y_val_targets, test_size=0.5, stratify=None, random_state=53)

def get_selected_dataset(ds, X_indices_np):
    # Make a tensor of type tf.int64 to match the one by Dataset.enumerate(). 
    X_indices_ts = tf.constant(X_indices_np, dtype=tf.int64)
    
    def is_index_in(index, rest):
        # Returns True if the specified index value is included in X_indices_ts.
        #
        # '==' compares the specified index value with each values in X_indices_ts.
        # The result is a boolean tensor, looks like [ False, True, ..., False ].
        # reduce_any() returns Ture if True is included in the specified tensor.
        return tf.math.reduce_any(index == X_indices_ts)
    
    def drop_index(index, rest):
        return rest

    # Dataset.enumerate() is similter to Python's enumerate().
    # The method adds indices to each elements. Then, the elements are filtered
    # by using the specified indices. Finally unnecessary indices are dropped.
    selected_ds = ds \
        .enumerate() \
        .filter(is_index_in) \
        .map(drop_index)
    return selected_ds
```